# AngularJS open PDF in new tab and change filename/url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

In my AngularJS Website I want to load .pdf documents and show them in new browser tabs. The following code works, but some things bother me:

The createdObjectURL is set as the title of the document and browser tab. That means my documents are always titled as somthing like `01d9bdca-9af2-43f0-a83f-f36fd82fd72` which is not really decent. And the visible URL isn't good, too. Instead of `blob:http://localhost:8080/01d9bdca-9af2-43f0-a83f-f36fd82fd72f` it would be better to have the URL I call in the service.js.

I tried to handle the filename in the HttpHeaders, but that has no effect at all :(

Another strange thing: if I do not specify the `{responseType: "arraybuffer"}`, the PDF-Title is displayed correctly. But there is no content, the document is empty.

Any help on how to change the filename and/or URL would be appreciated. Thank you.

**JS Controller**

```
DocumentService.getDocument().then(function(response) {
  $window.open(response, '_blank');
});
```

**JS Service**

```
return {
  getDocument : function () {
    return $http.get("document", {responseType: "arraybuffer"})
      .then(function(response) {
        var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/pdf"});
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        return fileURL;
      }
  }
}
```

**Spring MVC ReST-Service**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/document", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDocument(){
  try {
    File file = new File("C:\\pathToFile.pdf");
    byte[] fileContent = new byte[(int) file.lenth()];

    HttpHeaders heraders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    String filename = "NameOfFile.pdf";
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);  //doesn't change anything

    fileContent = File.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(fileContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

    return response;
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e ) {
    System.err.println("File not found " + e);
  } catch (IOException e ) {
    System.err.pringln("Error while reading file " + e);
  }
}
```

**Short version:**
When a PDF file is loaded as a byte array and displayed it in a new browser tab with the AngularJS $window directive: Is there a good possibility to change the filename and URL?

Comment: Can't you just open a new tab with the url to the resource returning the byte-array? Something like `$window.open('localhost:xxx/api/document', '_blank');`

Comment: Thank you @DanielBornstrand, this works. The window title is now just `document`, but the document title (if the document gets downloaded) is the one I specified. This is not 100 percent perfect, but way better than before and also less code :)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a new tab with the url to the resource returning the byte-array! Something like:

```
$window.open('localhost:xxx/api/document', '_blank');
```